# XAMPP iframe not working inside localhost

Tags: php, html, apache, iframe, localhost

I am trying to use an iframe to embed a pdf into a webpage. for some reason the pdf wont display (appears blank) and i'm prompted to download the file. This happens when i run the code from localhost server. however if i run the code outside localhost the iframe displays the pdf doc as it should. i have also tried using `<embed>` , `<object>` and pdf.js they all gave the same outcome.

**PHP FILE**

```
echo'<div class="main_content_view">
<iframe  src="pdf/pdf1.pdf" id="pdf_content"
width="700px" height="800px">
</iframe>
</div>
 ';
```

i've also tried adding `$cfg['AllowThirdPartyFraming'] = true;` to the config.inc.php and it still didnt work. Any ideas on how i could get the pdf to display in localhost as it does  when i right click and open the php directly with a browser?

Answer (score 0):

The thing is probably that a simple iFrame does not support viewing a PDF file. And afaik PDF.js is only for Firefox browser but I am not entirely sure about that. What you can try is [PDFObject](https://github.com/pipwerks/PDFObject).
This lets you dynamically embed your PDF in HTML documents using JS.